# "Hot-Swapping" Web Service References in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wcf

I've recently written prototype code that consumes a commercial web service that is hosted on ServerA.

I've added the reference through Visual Studio, written some code that calls a few exposed functions from the service and everything works great.

I'm now trying to change the reference to that web services to another URL, to target another server, ServerB. I BELIEVE the services on these two machines are the same.

However:
ServerA runs some version of the application which includes the deployed web service.
ServerB runs a different version of the application which includes the deployed web service.

Both WSDL contents are identical, the namespace addresses between the two are identical (the target namespace URLs are the same[note that the URLs both reference an external address e.g. http://google.com/services/whatever/]), but my prototype code only works when I reference the web service from ServerA.

I throw a "Fault occurred while processing." exception whenever calling an exposed function on ServerB. From my understanding this is an unhandled exception that is thrown server-side and it does not give me much info to debug.

If these web services were truly identical, would swapping out the endpoint URL in my application configuration be enough to switch references between the two web services or am I grossly misunderstanding something?

Comment: "would swapping out the endpoint URL in my application configuration be enough to switch references"

 Yes, after all, app.config/web.config are usually the only differences between the the finished development version & the deployed version, with the crucial differences are merely DB connection string and webservice URLs

Comment: As per @Martheen comment, yes in theory if the two services are the same version just hosted in different places you should be able to call either with your consuming code. I suspect there is a difference in server B which is causing you an issue.

Comment: Interesting! Unfortunately I can not reach the WSDLs as they are hosted on an internal environment that I do have access too. So I don't have a simple way of debugging my issue. I'm forced to build an executable, run it on a machine that does have access to the network, and do what I can.

Thanks for the information Martheen and Tom! I really appreciate your insight!